# Selectively turn off hyperref links

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm writing a document which includes a list of URLs that I want to be clickable, so I'm using hyperref to achieve this. This has the awkward side effect that my equation numbers, some of which I don't want to be clickable links, to also be clickable. I've hidden this by giving `hypersetup` the options `colorlinks, linkcolor={black}`

But this is suboptimal, in that the link is still clickable. I tried the following MWE, but it didn't work (the * just displays above the environment.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor={black}}
\title{This is the title}
\begin{document}
\let\oldref\ref
\let\ref\ref*
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:one}
  e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
\end{equation}
This is a link to the equation \ref{eq:one}, when it shouldn't be...
\let\ref\oldref %% Changing it back to normal behaviour
\end{document}
```

I also tried using renewcommand, but that failed too.

It's got something to do with the *, since `\let\ref\autoref` works fine.

I can't just find and replace the ones I want unlinked, because they are inside `LTXexample` environments, and I want the code to display as `\ref` not as `\ref*`

So I have two questions:

1. How do I get this temporary redefinition of `\ref` to work?
2. *Or*, how do I turn off equation links globally, but still have URL links work? (And if possible, is there a way to then have *some* equations linky with a different command)

Comment: Just to explain why `\let\ref\ref*` can't work: `*` is not letter, so the command is not `\ref*` but `\ref`, and this takes an optional argument `*`. So what you did was `\let\ref\ref` (not helpful `:-)`) and then typset `*`.

Comment: Would it be that bad to have clickable links all over if they didn't have any special colors or boxes around them in the PDF?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of `\ref*` use `\@refstar`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ref\@refstar
\makeatother
```

Why? hyperref redefines `\ref` this way.

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\ref{\@ifstar\@refstar\T@ref}%
```

`\@ifstar` is a LaTeX command which tests if the next character is a `*`. In this case the `*` would be gobbled and the first of the following commands will be executed (`\@refstar`), otherwise the second (`\T@ref`).

Thus, `\ref*` is essentially the same as `\@refstar` und you could use that instead.

If one would like to go deeper: the [source code documentation](http://sunsite.bilkent.edu.tr/pub/tex/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/hyperref.pdf) of hyperref (or [`hyperref.dtx` on CTAN](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/) or on your local TeX system) tells that `\HyRef@StarSetRef` belongs to `\ref*` and would not be linked, and `\@refstar` is defined this way:

```
\def\@refstar#1{%
  \HyRef@StarSetRef{#1}\@firstoffive
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just for the record, another simple way defined within the `hyperref package` would be to do the following:

```
\begin{NoHyper}              %% hyperref hyperlinking disabling environment!
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:one}
      e^{i\pi} + 1 = 0
  \end{equation}
\end{NoHyper}
```

Agreed, this won't disable all the necessary equation hyperlinks in one shot, but if needed a `hyperref` has already made it available for you, if you don't mind a bit of manual labour.