# Switch off all links except url and TOC when using hyperref

Tags: links

I am using `hyperref.sty` to create hyperlinks for TOC, web url, but I need to switch off all the cross links like `\ref, \cite` etc. Is this possible to fix and the MWE is follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[bookmarksopenlevel=1,dvips,bookmarks=true,colorlinks=true,breaklinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}%

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}\label{chap1}

\section{Heading level}\label{sec1}

Eq. \ref{eq1}

\begin{align}
a+b=c\label{eq1}
\end{align}

\newpage

\chapter{Test}\label{chap2}

Chapter \ref{chap2}

\section{Heading level}\label{sec2}

Eq. \ref{eq2}

\begin{align}
a+b=c\label{eq2}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

TOC and Bookmark and Web URL links should be enable and all the other links should be disable...

Comment: Does this answer help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117676/134144

Comment: @leandriis Thanks a lot, yes, this what I need exactly, but I need link for TOC pages also, can you suggest?

Comment: I did a bit of research and came up with another idea: To suppress the hyperlinks in `\ref` use `\ref*` instead. To suppress hyperlinks for `\cite` commands you could define your own macro as discussed here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118182/134144