# breakable in tcolorbox - it does not break

Tags: tcolorbox, break-box

**Update 21st March 2020**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8]{report}
%%
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%%
%% Header and Footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
%%
%% Figures and Graphs
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfigure,float}
%\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor,subfigure,float}% for pictures
\graphicspath{{./Pictures/}}
%% Font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default,angular]{comicneue}
%% QR code for classroom
\usepackage{qrcode}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\theoremstyle{plain}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example and Solution
%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\tcbset{%
    colback=white,
    tikz={opacity=1,transparency group},
    colframe=black,
%   breakable,
    title filled=false,
%   bookmark={Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    number within=section
    ]{example}{ +O{}mo }{%
    fonttitle    = \bfseries,
    title        = {Example~\thetcbcounter:~ #2},
    before lower = {\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
%   lowerbox     = invisible, %invisible/ignored
% after title/after upper
    IfValueTF={#3}{after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{\texttt #3 }}}{},
    #1
}%



\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\graphicspath{{./Pictures/bino_dist/}}



\begin{example}{Symmetry of binomial distribution}
A bag contains a large number of red and white discs, of which $85\%$ are red. 
$20$ discs are taken from the bag. 
Find the probability that the number of red discs lies between $12$ and $17$ inclusive.
\tcblower 
%%%%% 
%%%%% Let $X$ be the number of red discs. So $X \sim B(20,0.85)$. We want
\begin{equation}
    P(12 \leq X \leq 17) = P(X \leq 17) - P(X \leq 11)
\end{equation}
Then we notice that the table only gives the probabilities for $p$ up to 0.5. 
We have to go back to Figure~\ref{fig:bino-pdf} and think about using symmetry of the Binomial distribution.\\
%%%%% 

Let $Y$ be the number of white discs and $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$. So we have
\begin{align}
    P(12 \leq X \leq 17)
    &=
    P( 3 \leq Y \leq  8) \\
    &=
    P(Y \leq 8) - P(Y \leq 2) \\
    &=
    0.9987-0.4049 \\
    &=
    0.5938
\end{align}



The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.
%%
%%
The blue lines are ``probability'' of interest. 
The graphs on the left are the full plot of the distribution, where the graphs on the right are zoomed in on the area of interest. 
The top row represents the $X \sim B(20,0.85)$ distribution and the bottom row represents the $Y \sim B(20,0.15)$ distribution.


\end{example}





\cleardoublepage
%\renewcommand{\CoverName}{Back Cover}
%\renewcommand{\thepage}{\CoverName}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering
\mbox{}
\vfill
\huge{[This page is intentionally left blank.]
\vfill

\end{document}
```

See this new MWE, in this file, I have taken on board with the suggestion to put `breakable` in the `tcbset`. But if I use it, when there are **too** many content for the box, it gives an error and does not produce anything. Without the `breakable` in the `tcbset`, it compiles but it does not break the content at all.

**OP**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,UTF8]{report}  
\usepackage{amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage[top=1cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Example and Solution
%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\tcbset{%
    colback=white,
    tikz={opacity=0.1,transparency group},
    colframe=black,
    title filled=false,
%   bookmark={Q\arabic{\tcbcounter}}
}
\NewTColorBox[
    auto counter,
    %number within=section
    ]{example}{ +O{}mo }{%
    fonttitle    = \bfseries,
    title        = {Example~\thetcbcounter:~ #2},
    before lower = {\textbf{Solution~\thetcbcounter:\quad}},
%   lowerbox     = invisible, %invisible/ignored
% after title/after upper
    IfValueTF={#3}{after title={\hfill\colorbox{red}{\texttt #3 }}}{},
    #1
}%

%%
%% FIX FLOATS
%\makeatletter
%\newenvironment{fixedfigure}
%   {\def\@captype{figure}\center}
%   {\endcenter}
%\makeatother
%%
%% find the float
%%
%\makeatletter
%\let\old@error\@latexerr
%\def\zzfl@error{Float(s) lost}
%
%\def\@latexerr#1{%
%\def\tmp{#1}%
%\ifx\tmp\zzfl@error
%  \def\@elt##1{{%
%   \let \protect\noexpand
%    \shipout\vbox{\hbox{LOST FLOAT}\hbox{\fbox{\box##1}}}}}%
%  \@currlist\@dbltoplist 
%  \let\@elt\relax
%\fi
%\old@error{#1}}
%\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%







\begin{document}

\section*{Finding the PDF of a function of a continuous random variable}
% [lowerbox = invisible]
\begin{example}[lowerbox = invisible]{}
The continuous random variable $X$ has PDF $\mathrm{f}(x)$ given by
\[
    \mathrm{f}(x)
    =
    \begin{cases}
        4x^3 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\]
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Find $\mathrm{F}(x)$.
\item The continuous random variable $Y$ is given by $Y=X^3$. 
The cumulative distribution function of $Y$ is denoted by $\mathrm{H}(y)$. 
Find $\mathrm{H}(y)$.
\item Find $\mathrm{h}(y)$.
\item Find $\mathrm{P}(X<0.5)$.
\item Find $\mathrm{P}(Y<0.5)$.
\end{enumerate}
%%
%%
\tcblower
%%
%%
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
    \[
        \mathrm{F}(x)
        =
        \int_0^x 
        4s^3 \, \mathrm{d}s
        =
        x^4.
    \]
    Hence
    \[
        \mathrm{F}(x)
        =
        \begin{cases}
            0 & x<1 \\
            x^4 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
            1 & x>1
        \end{cases}
    \]
\item
    \[
        \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{H}(y) 
        &= \mathrm{P}(Y \leq y) \\
        &= \mathrm{P}(X^3 \leq y) \\
        &= \mathrm{P}(X \leq y^{\frac13}) \\
        &= (y^{\frac13})^4 \\
        &= y^\frac43
        \end{aligned}
    \]
    Hence
    \[
        \mathrm{H}(y)
        =
        \begin{cases}
            0         &  y<1 \\
            y^\frac43 &  0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
            1         &  y>1
        \end{cases}
    \]
\item
    \[
        \mathrm{h}(y)
        =
        \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}y} \mathrm{H}(y)
        =
        \frac{4}{3}y^{\frac13}
    \]
    \[
        \mathrm{h}(y)
        =
        \begin{cases}
            \frac{4}{3}y^{\frac13} & 0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
            0                      & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \]
\item
    \[
        \mathrm{P}(X<0.5)
        =
        \mathrm{F}(0.5)
        =
        0.5^4
        =
        \frac{1}{16}.
    \]
\item
    \[
        \mathrm{P}(Y<0.5)
        =
        \mathrm{H}(0.5)
        =
        0.5^\frac43
        =
        0.39685
    \]
\end{enumerate}
%%
%%
More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text More text 
\end{example}




\begin{example}{}
The continuous random variable $X$ has PDF $\mathrm{f}(x)$ given by
\[
    \mathrm{f}(x)
    =
    \begin{cases}
        2(1-x) & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
        0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\]
The continuous random variable $Y$ is given by $Y=(1-X)^2$.
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item Find $\mathrm{h}(y)$, the probability density function of $Y$ and name the distribution that it represents.
\item Find $\mathrm{P}(X<0.9)$.
\item Find $\mathrm{P}(Y<0.9)$.
\end{enumerate}
%%
%%
\tcblower
%%
%%
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
\item
    \[
        \mathrm{F}(x)
        =
        \int_0^x 
        2(1-x) \, \mathrm{d}s
        =
        2x-x^2
        =
        \begin{cases}
            0      & x<1 \\
            2x-x^2 & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
            1      & x>1
        \end{cases}
    \]
    \[
        \begin{aligned}
        \mathrm{H}(y)
        =
        \mathrm{P}(Y \leq y)
        =
        \mathrm{P}( (1-X)^2 \leq y)
        =
        1-\mathrm{P}(X \leq 1-\sqrt{y})
        =
        y
        \end{aligned}
    \]
    Hence
    \[
        \mathrm{H}(y)
        =
        \begin{cases}
            0 &  y<1 \\
            y &  0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
            1 &  y>1
        \end{cases}
    \]
    So
    \[
        \mathrm{h}(y)
        =
        \begin{cases}
            1 &  0 \leq y \leq 1 \\
            0 &  \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \]
    $Y$ is a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, that is $Y \sim U(0,1)$.
\item
    \[
        \mathrm{P}(X<0.9)
        =
        \mathrm{F}(0.9)
        =
        0.99
    \]
\item
    \[
        \mathrm{P}(Y<0.9)
        =
        \mathrm{H}(0.9)
        =
        0.9
    \]  
\end{enumerate}
%%
%%
\end{example}


\end{document}
```

See the output of the box, which does not appear to be breakable at all, even with the option `\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}` enabled.

If I comment out the last texts in the first example, the box goes into the footer like this.
[image]

Comment: Add `breakable,` to the `\tcbset`, to switch it on. It is initially false (document, 18.3 Main option keys, page 376). Also, remove the `[lowerbox = invisible]`, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Although the box still breaks when its content is invisible. Handy, that's a clue to the size of the solution :)

Comment: Adding a `\newpage` before the second-last `\item` in Example 1 gives a bit of breathing room around the footer.

Comment: @Cicada `breakable` to the `\tcbset` seem to work for the small example, but it caused a n `Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!` for the actual project ...might be a clash with some other package??

Comment: The old method of commenting out packages would help identify the one(s) causing it. Perhaps just a copy of the full project but with only the preamble, and an `x` in the `\begin{document}` `\end{document}` part.

Comment: It's also possible that some maximum count or value has been exceeded.

Comment: @Cicada hmmmm, looking at `! pdfTeX error (ext4): destinations cannot be inside an XForm.`  I might open another post for a more specific question. Thanks!

Comment: @Cicada See the new example, `breakable`, to the `\tcbset` does not seem to be working at all when there is `too much` content in the box and it won't compile. I can delete the content and shorten the box, then it compiles. Really don't know where the problem is ....

Comment: Manual 18.2: The maximal total height ... normal breakable
tcolorboxes is about 65536pt (ca. 2300cm) apiece. If such a part gets longer, the output
will get buggy without warning. For very oversized boxes which are longer than 65536pt,
use the unlimited value for /tcb/breakableÕP. 376. With the unlimited setting, the
applied algorithm has (virtually) no height limit for boxes, but very likely the compiler
memory will have to be increased for boxes longer than 300 pages (depending on compiler
settings and box content). But it is recommended to use unlimited for critical large boxes
only.

Comment: Do `texdoc tcolorbox` to bring up the manual.

Comment: @Cicada Very strange... It does *NOT* work for the MWE, but tried with some other documents, the `effect` of `breakable=unlimited` is clear. It also `shortened` the space between and after the boxes.

Comment: Any updates? Still the same problem...

Comment: The error message "destinations cannot be inside an xform" relates to links. Experiment indicates that commenting out hyperref, `%\usepackage{hyperref}`, allows breakable boxes. The packages are not playing nice with each other.

Comment: Put the long example inside a `NoHyper` environment (idea from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116338/how-to-turn-on-off-certain-types-e-g-citation-url-file-of-hyperref-links/117676#117676). Works OK.