# tcolorbox[breakable] does not break in overleaf

Tags: tcolorbox, page-breaking

The following code produces three levels of nested boxes in Overleaf. Since each can have a lot of text, I need them to break between multiple pages as needed; but only some do, while others overflow the page, making them impossible to read.

I've tried many solutions, including the suggestions in the comments of [this unsolved post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/532531/breakable-in-tcolorbox-it-does-not-break).

Any idea?

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse,breakable}
\tcbset{%
    breakable,
    title filled=false}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\large {\textbf{Table 1.} Caption.}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, colback=white]
\centering\textbf{\Large Title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, colback=gray!20]
{\textbf{Intro}\newline}
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, colback=yellow!50]
{\textbf{First Section}\newline}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, colback=blue!20]
{\textbf{Subsection 1.1}\newline}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, enhanced, colback=gray!20]
{\textbf{Subsection 1.2}\newline}
\lipsum[6-7]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I would be surprised if there was an easy way to make your nested boxes breakable: `tcolorbox`'s manual states: "you cannot not nest a breakable box inside a breakable box. The `breakable` key for a nested box is ignored automatically, i. e. inner boxes are always unbreakable." (p. 399)

Comment: It's not an `Overleaf` problem, inner boxes are not breakable as already `Vincent` mentioned

Comment: `\large {\textbf{Table 1.} Caption.}` makes the whole document large not just the caption, did you intend `{\large \textbf{Table 1.} Caption.}` ?