# Overriding hyperref in TikZ/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, hyperref

Is it possible to override the `hyperref` instruction of showing the references in a specific colour but only within the context of `TikZ` and `pgfplots`? The problem is that I am using `legend to ref` and `\ref` in a `tikzpicture` environment and the text of the legend becomes blue because of the `hyperref` global setting. I don't know how to force legend's text colour or even if that would work, but the solution I am looking for should be something that can be set globally in the preamble if possible.

## MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor={blue}]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      % \hypersetup{hidelinks} % jfbu's solution: Uncomment to get black text.
      \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
          group size=2 by 1,},]
        \nextgroupplot[scale only axis,width=0.35\textwidth,height=0.35\textwidth,legend to name=grouplegend,]
        \addplot
          coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
        \addlegendentry{Legend 1}
        \nextgroupplot[scale only axis,width=0.35\textwidth,height=0.35\textwidth]
        \addplot
          coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
      \end{groupplot}
      \node (legend) at ($(group c1r1.south)!0.5!(group c2r1.south)$)
        [below, yshift=-3\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/every axis title shift}]
        {\ref{grouplegend}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \caption{The caption.}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

jfbu's solution of placing `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` in the `tikzpicture` environment works by maintaining the links (I'm not interested in that) but showing the text in black. I'm looking for a way to achieve this globally though.

Comment: I have successfully used `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` inside a group (and environments create groups) in the past to address a similar issue. This cures the color problem by suppressing the links. I sort of remember having tried unsuccessfully to change the linkcolor using similarly other `hyperref` options locally.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I am a beginner. Sorry.

Comment: Just insert `\hypersetup{hidelinks}` as the first thing inside your tikzpicture. Perhaps this will work.

Comment: @jfbu: Placing it inside the `tikzpicture` environment works. But I need something that can be set globally.
@Jake: Yes, I'm editing my post now.

Comment: @sudosensei: You can set the option for all `tikzpicture`s using `\tikzset{
 every picture/.style={
  execute at begin picture=\hypersetup{hidelinks}
 }
}`

Comment: @Jake: It works great! Thank you so much. Could you please convert this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @jfbu: Could you write up an answer?

Comment: @Jake: please do; I so rarely did things with `tikzpicture` that I could not decently be credited with an answer related to its use...

Comment: @Jake, and additionnally I said this would suppress the links, but it seems it does not, it just suppresses the color.

Comment: @jfbu: It does because I externalize the `tikzpicture`. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While scouring through the `pgfplots` manual, I happened to stumble upon a more elegant solution. Simply, instead of invoking a command that temporarily suspends `hyperref` before each picture, it is possible to just replace `\ref{refname}` with `\pgfplotslegendfromname{refname}`.

From the `pgfplots` manual on page 189:

> `\pgfplotslegendfromname{<name>}`
>   This command poses an equivalent alternative for `\ref{<name>}`: it has
>   essentially the same effect, but it does not create links when used
>   with the `hyperref` package.

Comment: Oh, that's indeed much more elegant! Good find! You should accept this instead of my answer, so others can find the proper approach more easily.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the `hyperref` links in `tikzpicture`s by using Stefan Kottwitz's approach from [Selectively turn off hyperref links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/selectively-turn-off-hyperref-links) and wrapping it in `execute at begin picture`:

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    every picture/.style={
        execute at begin picture={
            \let\ref\@refstar
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
```

[image]